# How to select element from HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom

I am trying to select elements from the HTML Element. But not working. How to do it? I have used query selector but it is not working. Only it is working inside settimeout. Without settimeout how to achieve?

**HTML:** Getting this from `console.log(drop);`

```
<div class="container">
<dropdown-part>
 <select>
 <option>2</option>
 </select>
</dropdown-part>
</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
let dropcover = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.container') as HTMLElement;
console.log(drop);
 
console.log(dropcover.querySelector('dropdown-part')); // Getting null

setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(dropcover.querySelector('dropdown-part')); // working
},0);
```

Comment: Have you tried dropcover.childNodes and selecting the dropdown-part from the nodelist?

Comment: @Esszed: Can you edit my code?

Comment: @Esszed:  dropcover.childNodes.querySelector('dropdown-part');  Not Working

Comment: If dropcover returns the provided html code you can select <dropdown-part> with dropcover.childNodes[1]

Comment: @Esszed: dropcover.childNodes[1].innerHTML   not working

Comment: Can you provide more code and your intent?

Comment: @Esszed: Why it is Working only inside setTimeout?

Comment: @Esszed: I have edited my question. Please check and answer it.